# Javascript ES6 Destructuring Nested Object Parent and Child Assign variable

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, assign, destructuring

**I Destructuring first variable nested objects within parent then I declare another variable to set a child value but there some error I don't know which sufficient way to solve this and readable**

```
let personObj = {
        Name: 'Robiul',
        Age: 22,
        Address: {
            city: 'Dhaka',
            country: 'Bangladesh'
        }
    }

    let {Address: myAddress} = personObj
    let {myAddress:{city: myCity, country: myCountry}}=myAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you have already destructured, `Address` out into `myAddress`. 
So you would not require one more layer of nesting when de structuring it.

```js
    let personObj = {
        Name: 'Robiul',
        Age: 22,
        Address: {
            city: 'Dhaka',
            country: 'Bangladesh'
        }
    }

    // destructure address and rename it to myAddress
    let { Address: myAddress } = personObj;
    
    // destructure myAdress and rename city and country
    let { city: myCity, country: myCountry } = myAddress;
    
    console.log('city', myCity, 'country', myCountry);
```

Also since you are not really using `myAddress` anywhere, you can just destructure this out from `personObj`.

```js
let personObj = {
  Name: 'Robiul',
  Age: 22,
  Address: {
    city: 'Dhaka',
    country: 'Bangladesh'
  }
}

// destructure address and rename it to myAddress
let {
  Address: {
     city: myCity,
     country: myCountry
  }
} = personObj;


console.log('city', myCity, 'country', myCountry);
```

Comment: let {Address:myAddress,  {city: myCity, country: myCountry}}=personObj
this way inlien to assign to is it possible

Comment: Once you destructure an object, `Address` ( in this case ), you won't have a reference of it anymore. So if you want to have an handle of both `myAddress`, then you will have to pick them again.  `let { Address : myAddress, Address: { city: myCity, country: myCountry } } = personObj `

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
const {Address: myAddress} = personObj;
const {city: myCity, country: myCountry} = myAddress;
console.log(myAddress, myCity, myCountry);
```

or

```
const {Address: {city: myCity, country: myCountry}} = personObj;
console.log(myCity, myCountry); // notice no myAddress variable
```

or

```
const {Address: myAddress, Address:{city: myCity, country: myCountry}} = personObj;
console.log(myAddress, myCity, myCountry);
```

Comment: That last one is the one I was looking for.